# Connecting an ethernet-only gaming PC to the network where an ethernet cable cannot be used?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

I have a gaming PC that I want to connect to my `450Mbps` home network. The PC has a single LAN port supporting up to `1000Mbps`, but no builtin WiFi adapter and no free PCI/PCIe slots. I would like to avoid sacrificing a USB3 port for a wireless dongle, and I've had poor experiences with such devices in the past.

In previous homes, I've simply run a direct Ethernet cable between the modem and computer with no issue. Unfortunately, I am moving to a new home where the room where the computer will live does not have a network jack, and the modem is likely to be installed in the adjacent garage. I am not able to run any visible cable through the hallway between the two rooms, regardless of whether it's on the floor or attached to the roof. The property is a rental, and I am not allowed to make any modifications to the walls, and the landlord was unwilling to add a network jack in the office (even at my cost).

The rooms look roughly like this:

```
|         |         |
| Office  |         |
|_________| Hallway |
          |         |_________
          |         |         |
          |         | Garage  |
          |         |         |
```

I had considered a Powerline adapter as an option, but unfortunately, I think the circuits for the office and garage are different and thus it would be a reduced connection speed (if it works at all), which I want to avoid.

What options do I have to get the best network performance given these factors?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I think you could use an (old) WiFi router as a WiFi extender, and then connect your PC to that using an ethernet cable.

Comment: I do actually have an old TP-Link modem/router, although it's an ISP-provided one so I have no idea if it's got all the required features and what the network performance/latency is going to be like. I might trial that kind of setup tonight if I can figure out how to configure it.

Comment: Most wifi routers have the ability to work as a client device. You didn't mention the exact type of router, but have a look at https://www.tp-link.com/nl/support/faq/1606/ and see whether your routers does the samen.

Comment: @Paul Ah! This was the feature I was looking for, I got stuck looking how to configure "bridge mode". Thanks for that. I'm going to give it a try in this house I'm moving out of as it's roughly similar distances with similar equipment to where I'm going (only different is I can do a direct ethernet connection here).

Comment: Even though you don’t want to, I’d suggest going “native Wi-Fi” anyway. In most situations, it will offer the best performance with the least unwanted surprises. Maybe you still have an M.2 slot free?

Comment: @DanielB The motherboard is an ASRock B450 Steel Legend. Please correct me if I'm wrong, I think it only has a single M.2 slot, which is currently loaded with my primary NVMe drive.

Comment: This board has two M.2 slots, however one of them is mutually exclusive with the second PCIe x16 slot. // But there sure are lots of PCIe slots. Are all of them really occupied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating a Mesh network using hardware purchased from my ISP while setting up my contract.

From my ISP I purchased a NetComm CloudMesh Gateway (NF20MESH) with one CloudMesh Satellite (NS-02) at a discounted price. The satellite has two ethernet ports which allowed me to connect to my PC, and I've been easily able to achieve the desired speeds.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for "best" network performance I wouldn't necessarily go with old devices as the comments suggest. Find some that can actually give you 450Mbps, you should be fine as long as you plan with sufficient reserve (for signal loss as well as overhead).

Basically, you have two options, use a WiFi bridge (also called point-to-point wireless bridge) or use a Powerline bridge as you suggested (essentially also as a point-to-point bridge) which you try to avoid.

In the end, your choice should depend on these factors:

- distance and materials in your walls if you use a Wi-Fi bridge
- distance and circuitry of your power lines if you use a Powerline bridge
- interference from other devices (especially with Wi-Fi)

For Wi-Fi you want to look for directional Wi-Fi antennas for the bridge instead of omnidirectional. You'll have to play around with the bandwidth (e.g. 2.4 vs. 5 Ghz), in general, lower Ghz usually has better penetration through walls etc. but lower data transfer rates.

You can use specialized devices dedicated to creating a (point to point) Wi-Fi bridge e.g. TPlink, UBI etc. depending on your budget. Just make sure you choose the right device for your use case ("for a few meters with obstacles in the way" instead of "outside with distance and line of sight").

You can also use regular devices, and manually configure the Wi-Fi bridge. Whatever you have already lying around e.g. two consumer "routers". One would be configured as an AP (No Routing, No DHCP) and one as the "corresponding client" connecting to the AP (make sure it's WISP capable so it can also connect to a WLAN AP and not only serve as an AP). Personally, I would go with an AP with a directional Antenna and a Rasberry Pie with an external and directional antenna on the other end.

There are a few other alternatives like Bluetooth, Li-Fi etc, but they are not fit for your use case.

In the end, there are a lot of options, you need to be more specific about your requirements and resources.

Comment: I'll have a check for WiFi antennas, thank you for this.

Comment: @YetAnotherStackExchangeUser A Wi-Fi bridge with two devices (and a directional antenna) is (the same as) a point to point wireless connection.

Comment: @YetAnotherStackExchangeUser any news?

Answer (score 0):

A pair of "point to point" wireless bridges. They are (somewhat) directional, making them both more powerful and more sensitive in one direction – e.g. in practice they can reach several km at the same overall transmit power limit as your home wifi – so the link should easily cross the hallway through the walls, even if set to "lowest" power. (Although I'd probably suggest mounting them on the ceiling, above heads.)

These usually support both standard 802.11 Wi-Fi and their proprietary WISP-optimized mode. For a simple two-device connection you'll be fine with the former, and it may actually be enough to have just one bridge connected to a regular wifi access point.

The hardware might be slightly expensive, but once you set it up, it just works for years without any interruption. (Unlike my experience with 'powerline' equipment so far.)

```
┌────────────────────────────────┬───┬──────────────────────────────┐
│ Office:                        │   │ Garage:                      │
│                                │   │                              │
│ [computer] ==== [Nanostation) ~│~~~│~ (Nanostation] ==== [switch] │
└────────────────────────────────┴───┴──────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can borrow a pair to do a quick test, this looks like the cleanest solution. If it all works out, this'll probably be what I mark as the answer.

Comment: An important specification: Point to point wireless bridges *are* directional (not somewhat directional). If they are not directional, they are either point to multi-point bridges (which is not what the OP want unless he wants to connect a second room etc.) or just very bad design.

Comment: What is WISP-optimized mode?

Comment: @Albin: Usually some form of TDMA-based protocol, like Ubiquiti's airMax or LigoWave's iPoll2/iPoll3 or Mikrotik's Nstreme/Nv2.

Comment: @Albin: The (old) Nanostation bridges we used to use had like a 60° angle, so definitely more PtMP than PtP, but they work perfectly well for PtP usage as well (especially if it's at a short distance); it's not fundamentally incompatible with that kind of usage or anything. I think it's still the same for the current versions. (The slightly newer LigoDLB, it seems, has a 15° angle so that definitely seems PtP only. It picks up my smartphone from my bus stop a ~km away.) I was going to suggest either a Nanostation Loco 5ac or whatever Mikrotik has for similar price.

Comment: @u1686_grawity why would you need TDMA for a point to point connection?

Comment: @u1686_grawity not really, 60° angle is not perfect for PtP (that's the whole point) unless the OP wants PtMP in the future. Not really sure the UBI or Mikrotik will give you the best value if you try to bridge one hallway (the OP just needs 450Mbps). The main problem to consider is not the distance but the obstructing objects.

Comment: You don't, it's for PtMP usage. I specifically said OP doesn't need it, even.

Comment: @u1686_grawity Ah I see, I overlooked "the former"...  what's the data rate with UBI? I find UBI works better as part of a "whole UBI network", did you use them as "stand-alone" devices to create a bridge?

Answer (score 0):

I would double-check and see if your motherboard supports a wireless card first. I have two desktop PCs that use internal laptop Wi-Fi cards, and I believe that's the only thing the slot on the board can be used for.

My other fix for this issue would be to pick up a "personal mini travel router". I think any model with OpenWRT will provide the required functionality may be less expensive than a similar residential router, and will take up less space.

[https://www.amazon.com/GL-iNet-GL-SFT1200-Secure-Travel-Router/dp/B09N72FMH5/ref=sr_1_10?crid=1BXY4KC479KX2&keywords=GL-MT300N-V2&qid=1695130177&s=electronics&sprefix=gl-mt300n-v2%2Celectronics%2C102&sr=1-10&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09N72FMH5)